# Overriding __new__ and __init__ in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python's use of __new__ and __init__ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)

The way I understand it, `__init__` is different from a constructor in Java, because `__init__` only initializes an object that has already been constructed implicitly (because `__init__` is called after `__new__`). However, everything that I have ever needed to define has used this latter property of a 'constructor' in Java. What would be a case in which a programmer would want to override `__new__`?

**EDIT**: For the record, I ask partly because I'm wondering what would be the advantage/disadvantage to overriding **new** vs. using a separate classmethod in the accepted answer to this question:

[Moving Beyond Factories in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571773/moving-beyond-factories-in-python)

Comment: Not quite an exact duplicate in my eyes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`__new__` actually happens before an object exists. It's a static method of the type. Uses of `__new__` are when you want to control the creation of new objects, e.g. a singleton. If your `__new__` always returns the same instance of an object, it's a singleton. You can't do that with `__init__`.

Generally, in "python as Guido intended it to be" you shouldn't use `__new__` more than once a month :)

Comment: That makes sense. So is this (the accepted answer below) a case where overriding __new__ would also be appropriate?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571773/moving-beyond-factories-in-python

Answer (score 3):

`__new__` is for creating new object instance, `__init__` is for initializing it.

I think if you design an immutable type, you have to initialize it in `__new__`, see `namedtuple` for example (also [Python's use of __new__ and __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)).