# limiting total number of instances by overriding __new__ in python

Tags: python

I am reading a [blog post](https://howto.lintel.in/python-__new__-magic-method-explained/) on examples of overriding `__new__` in python. However, I don't understand the following example:

```
class LimitedInstances(object):
    _instances = []  # Keep track of instance reference
    limit = 5 

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if not len(cls._instances) <= cls.limit:
        raise RuntimeError, "Count not create instance. Limit %s reached" % cls.limit    
    instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    cls._instances.append(instance)
    return instance

def __del__(self):
    # Remove instance from _instances 
    self._instance.remove(self)
```

Wouldn't calling `object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` cause infinite recursion? In addition, I saw that [`__new__` actually happens before an object exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584042/overriding-new-and-init-in-python). Then what is stored in `cls` exactly?

Comment: The blog post you linked provides an answer to your 2nd question:
"Method __new__ will take class reference as the first argument"

Comment: @nicoco ok...I think I mixed up object reference and class reference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This code example is broken. `_instances` keeps a reference to each of its elements, and `__del__` is only called when an object has zero references. Thus, an object can never be removed from `_instances` as it being present in `_instances` guarentees it has a reference count of at least 1.

Comment: In fact it's all sorts of broken. It limits creation to `limit+1` instances, probably not the expected behaviour. And it may call `object.__new__` with non-empty `args` or `kwargs` which is an error. It's also written in Python 2. I would suggest this blog is not a great resource for learning Python 3 or even Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `object.__new__` in `LimitedInstances.__new__` does not cause infinite recursion because they are different functions and `object.__new__` does not call back to `LimitedInstances.__new__`. The call heiraracy looks something like:

```
LimitedInstances()
    LimitedInstances.__new__(LimitedInstances)
        object.__new__(LimitedInstances)
    object.__init__(instance) # (as there is not LimitedInstances.__init__)
```

It can get a bit more complicated than that, but in general this is what happens when you call a class.

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't calling `object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` cause infinite recursion?

Nope, why ? `object.__new__` is not `LimitedInstances.__new__` and will not call `LimitedInstances.__new__` either.

nb : it would be better to use `super()` instead of hardcoding  `object`, but that's unrelated.

> in addition, I saw that **new** actually happens before an object exists.

Indeed - `__new__` is the real constructor - it's responsability is precisely to create a new (uninitialized) instance of `cls`.

> Then what is stored in cls exactly?

The class itself (in your case, `LimitedInstances`). How would you know (well, how would `object.__new__` know) which class should be instanciated else ?-)